# Get generic class from list in c#

Tags: c#, generics

How can I loop through and get generic class from a list in c#. My code is like this.

```
private void processList()
{
    List<CommandParameter> parameters = new List<CommandParameter>();
    parameters.Add(new CommandParameter<string>("a", "c", "a"));
    parameters.Add(new CommandParameter<int>("a", "c", 1));

    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
    {
        // How can I loop through the parameters list and get the generic class
    }
}
```

Is this possible? Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

this is command parameter classes

```
public class CommandParameter<T> : CommandParameter{
    public string Str { get; private set; }
    public string TypeName { get;private  set; }
    public T TypeValue { get; private set; }

    public CommandParameter(string s, string typeName, T typeValue) {
        Str = s;
        TypeName  = typeName;
        TypeValue = typeValue;
    }
}

public abstract class CommandParameter {

}
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "and get the generic class"? What do you expect the result to be in the example you've given? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: i want to get the`commandParameter<string>` and `commandParameter<int>`from the list in the loop

Comment: So just call `parameter.GetType()`, presumably.

Comment: `Type t = parameter.GetType()` right? but then how can i access the fields? do i have to use reflection?

Comment: Yes, you would have to. Or use dynamic typing to dynamically perform type inference (calling a generic method). You still haven't explained what you're trying to do, which makes it harder to help you.

Comment: What is `CommandParameter<T>`, where does it come from?

Comment: @JonSkeet i want to loop through the list and get the values of the fields in that generic class

Comment: @poke `CommandParameter<T>` is the subclass of `CommandParameter` and it is just an empty abstract class,only used to specify the parameter type

Comment: Okay, then what is `CommandParameter`? I really have no idea what that type looks like, and it’s hard to answer the question without knowing that. Is that a type in the standard library, or where does it come from?

Comment: @poke i have edited my question. `CommandParameter` is a custom class, not from the standard library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are looking for the generic argument's, here is an example:

```
List<IEnumerable> coll = new List<IEnumerable>();

coll.Add(new List<string> { "a", "b" });
coll.Add(new List<int> { 7 });

foreach (var item in coll)
{
    var args = item.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
    foreach (var genericArg in args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(genericArg); // generic types (e.g. string, int)
    }
}
```